# Main Menu. Best practices.

Tags: c#, winforms, menu, design-patterns

I use Windows Forms, but I don't know this library well. I need to create main menu. I do now:

I create Windows Form. On it I create two panels: pnlMainMenu (dock = top) and pnlWindow (dock = fill). I will use pnlMainMenu for menu, pnlWindow for drawing some figures.

On pnlTools I create menu: System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip MainMenu (dock = top) and panel pnlTools (dock = fill). I will use pnlTools for different instruments.

In this way I will have a lot of controls on my form. Do I need to create new WindowsForm for MainMenu only? For example:

```
menuForm = new MainMenuForm();
menuForm.pnlMainMenu.Parent = this.pnlMainMenu;
menuForm.pnlMainMenu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: You create a different form for the menu, only to move the menu in runtime back to the main app form? This makes no sense. Please explain.

Comment: The idea is that this menu can be used in other forms. Also it will be easier to work with main form (for example, it will reduce the number of controls)

Comment: You can write a helper method that creates the menu. You can copy the code generated by the designer.

Comment: Well, if I use framework Qt, I will do it. But I use Windows Forms. It does not have MVC model and other advantages. 
So, I think,  the best way is create new form for menu.

Comment: still not sure if I understand your problem, but you wan't to minimize control amount is what I read. Have you tried wrapping it up in a Custom UserControl. In there you could also provide methods for reusing the same control on different forms + you need to bind only one control instead multiple (Panel + Menustrip). Another benefit is that you separate your Menu Logic from your form, that way a small step towards "MVC mini" :)

Comment: thanks. i will use a lot of controls (PictureBox) in this menu. Do I need use a list for them? Also  I want use hover, hints, and selection control on click (highlight). I can do it with designer, but I will have a lot of methods in MainForm (or in custom menu). Is it normal?

Comment: @novicegis I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms for pretty much anything. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about any longer. Microsoft did not update winforms since 2007. WPF has much greater support for design patterns (MVC / MVVM) and all the visual / interactivity features you're describing here will be a PITA in winforms, but really easy in WPF. winforms is pretty much deprecated, only used to maintain legacy applications, but not for any new projects.

Comment: It's also important to mention that if you don't already `know` winforms, don't waste your time trying to learn it. All newer Windows UI technologies are XAML-based and share the same mentality as WPF. If you learn WPF, you may port your knowledge and skills directly into other frameworks such as WinRT and Silverlight. If you learn winforms, you're stuck with winforms and similar dinosaur-like UI frameworks (such as java stuff swing and things like that)

Comment: Thanks, but we use this technology (winforms + devexpress, awt + swing) in our big projects for UI. I have some free time and I want to improve code. The problem is that I don't know WinForms normal (I can create good interfaces, but I think the code is terrible) 
I know Qt 3, Qt 4 because I used them when I was studing. Is there any similar technology for language c#?  any similar technology for language c#?

Comment: About WPF http://paulstovell.com/blog/six-years-of-wpf.

Asp.net mvc 4. Is it the best choise for c# programmer?

Comment: @novicegis regardless of that article, the default option for Windows Applications is WPF. The supposed lack of improvements that article speaks about are minimal when compared to the archaic ways of winforms. and of course Web Applications are a completely different matter.